# (De)serialize field containing JSON automatically when model is created

Tags: json, activerecord, serialization, yii

How would I go about doing this? I want to serialize and deserialize a JSON string when I fetch a model from my DB, so that I can access the stdObject directly without having to deserialize it myself each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can add this to your model, and change the explode/implode to suit your serialize/deserialize problem:

**Implode/Explode:**

```
protected function afterFind() {

    parent::afterFind();

    if($this->hasAttribute('types'))
        $this->types = explode('|', $this->types);

    return $this;
}

protected function beforeSave() {

    parent::beforeSave();

    if($this->hasAttribute('types'))
        $this->types = implode('|', $this->types);

    return $this;
}
```

The `if` statement is just a failsafe in case the field goes missing in the database (unlikely), or if you are using this code in the base model (as some models may not have this field). In most cases, it would be safe to exclude this check.

**JSON:**

```
protected function afterFind() {

    $this->types = json_decode($this->types);
    return parent::afterFind();
}

protected function beforeSave() {

    $this->types = json_encode($this->types);
    return parent::beforeSave();
}
```

Comment: I was asking for JSON, but this answers my question. Thank you. Would be great if you could update to JSON for passers-by. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a getter/setter. Say our DB column is called `jsonData`. Then you could write

```
public function getData()
{
    return json_decode($this->jsonData);
}

public function setData($value)
{
    $this->jsonData = json_encode($value);
}
```

`data` can then be used like a regular attribute.

Comment: The solution with afterFind/beforeSave is way more elegant.

Comment: The difference is, that you still have access to the JSON encoded data. I don't agree, that the other solution is more elegant. Using getters and setters is a very powerful technique that you should get used to.

Comment: It's always a bad idea to auto convert an attribute. E.g. in the above solution you suddenly end up with JSON in `types` after the `save()` operation (which is even worse, if the `save()` operation failed, e.g. because `type` was too long). Whereas in this solution you can even validate both fields independently. Now this is what I call *way way more elegant*. :P